# Implementing Topography map tile on Google Maps API

Tags: javascript

We have a requirement of using Google MAPS API to show resources in a state and we are able to show all the base map layers like Terrain and Satellite. but we are required to show Topo layer which i think is not available as a Base Map layer. What is the best way to go forward implementing TOPO layer using google map API? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you at least gathered some information in google? Have you tried something so far? Please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry Osakr if my question was not clear, As I have mentioned we have implemented the javascript API to display the base layers including Terrain and Satellite layers. It is just the Topo layer that we are not able to implement. I am looking to see if anyone has came across the same scenario and has implemented the same.

Comment: Your question is clear, sorry If i sounded rude, wasn't my intention. Is just that the question sounds a little broad